# Run the application multiple times with different arguments in one click

Tags: c, batch-file, cygwin, bulk

What I'm trying to do is run the same program multiple times in `Cygwin` but with different arguments passed to it.

What I try to do is as follows

`./ssltest.exe -3 -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP && ./ssltest.exe -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP && ./ssltest.exe -1 -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP && ./ssltest.exe -2 -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP`

But in something that would look like this

```
./bulkssltest.exe -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP
```

And present the same results. As you can see the port and IP remain the same but I run it with `-1`, `-2`, `-3` and with no additional arguments.

The code is way too complicated for me to edit it to achieve the same result but I am pretty sure there is a way to get it to work like this somehow.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you do it with a batch file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is there any reliable tutorial that would help me do so?

Comment: I don't know for Windows, this things are very easily achievable in linux.

Comment: Doesn't the semicolon separator work in Cygwin? (e.g., `./do-this ; ./then-do-that`)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage - yes it does.  IIRC, it's default shell is real-deal GNU bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Shell script for Cygwin

Put the following into a file, say `bulkssltest.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

for opt in -3 "" -1 -2; do
  # Intentionally unquoted $opt here, so that the empty opt disappears
  # and is not expanded into the empty string (that ssltest doesn't expect)
  # You might want to use an absolute path to ssltest.exe here.
  ./ssltest.exe $opt "$@" || break
done
```

**Make sure the file contains UNIX line endings,** or `/bin/sh` will complain about `$\r: command not found.` and similar things. The trick here is that `"$@"` expands to the arguments that were passed to the script and a slightly unusual unquoted use of the loop variable `$opt` to make it disappear when it is the empty string. `break` exits the loop, and it is invoked here if `ssltest` came back with a non-zero exit status (that's what the `||` does; it's the or to `&&`'s and).

Then:

```
chmod +x bulkssltest.sh
```

Then:

```
./bulkssltest.sh -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP
```

#### Alternatively, for pure Windows:

Looping in a batch file is, unfortunately, painful, as is shortcutting, and I have not found a way to expand an empty token to nothing the way I did in the shell script above, so to produce the precise results as the expression you posted, you'll have to repeat yourself. For example, put this into a file `bulkssltest.bat`:

```
@echo off

ssltest -3 %*
IF NOT %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 GOTO end
ssltest %*
IF NOT %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 GOTO end
FOR %%O IN (-2,-1) DO (ssltest %%O %* & IF NOT %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 GOTO end)

:end
```

and run

```
bulkssltest -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP
```

The `FOR` loop is included here for purposes of illustration; you could, of course, just do the last two calls to `ssltest` like the first two. Note that you cannot break this loop into several lines; `cmd` will not have it. If the order of execution does not matter, you can fold the call with `-3` into the loop and save some lines, but I don't think that is possible for the empty token. Here it is `%*` that expands to the arguments that were given to the batch file, `%ErrorLevel` is the exit status of the most recently executed program (akin to `$?` in shell scripts), and `:end` is a jump label.

If you want to do more complicated things with on-board Windows tools, I urge you to look into powershell. It does not get any better with batch files.

Comment: you could also, for windows, have the first two parameters be the port parameters, and use %3 and shift to successively access the remaining/changable parameters

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm. Will serve me as a learning point for future endeavors. You the man!

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand operator controls the command pipeline. It will only run each subsequent command if the previous one finished OK (ie: returned 0). I think you meant to use semicolon `;` which will run each command regardless of how the previous command exited.

```
./ssltest.exe -3 -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP ; \
./ssltest.exe -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP ; \
./ssltest.exe -1 -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP ; \
./ssltest.exe -2 -p STATIC_PORT STATIC_IP
```

FYI -- I added the backslash line continuation character to make the example readable. You put this command all on one line (just remove the backslashes)